# My getprocaddress function returns 0000 I've read that it's because I have to compile for ANSI instead of Unicode how do I do this?

Tags: c, dll

```c
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    HMODULE hModule = LoadLibrary(L"kernel32.dll");

    FARPROC func  = GetProcAddress(hModule, "LoadLibraryA");
    FARPROC func2 = GetProcAddress(hModule, "GetProcAddress");
    FARPROC func3 = GetProcAddress(hModule, "ExitProcess");

    printf("LoadLibraryA   0x%08x\n", (unsigned int)func);
    printf("GetProcAddress 0x%08x\n", (unsigned int)func2);
    printf("ExitProcess    0x%08x\n", (unsigned int)func3);

    FreeLibrary(hModule);
}
```

output:

```
LoadLibraryA   0x00000000
GetProcAddress 0x00000000
ExitProcess    0x00000000
```

Comment: MS says [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getprocaddress) *If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call [`GetLastError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror).*

Comment: ... and the same for [`LoadLibrary()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya) @WeatherVane

Comment: I removed the L from (L"kernel32.dll") and it started working